# sed: -i may not be used with stdin

Tags: php, macos, sed, stdin

In PHP I use proc_open() to pass a sed() request through stdin.

However

```
sed -i -e 's/USE `.*`;//'
```

results in:

> sed: -i may not be used with stdin

When I run the same command in shell it works OK.

Any takers? Cannot find any answers.

Please note that the reason for using **sed -i** is that because the file in question is a large one (1 GB).

Comment: How do you propose to edit standard input in place?

Comment: Not sure. I am wondering what would be the best way to get around this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The -i flag means sed opens the files, modifies them, then saves them.

Since you cannot save stdin, the -i flag does not make sense to use with stdin.

to make it do something that makes sense, either provide the file on the command line (which will modify the file in place) or remove the -i flag and the modified input will be printed to stdout.

Comment: sed -i is instructed to update a file with a size of 1 GB. What would you recommend to do instead? Obviously printing the output to stdout is not really an option.

Comment: then clearly the remaining option is `sed -i pattern filename`